# automatically kill process on "Stop Debugging" in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

My c# application executes a second process, when I stop the debugging the second process lives on and I can't rebuild because the .exe of the process is still in use.

How can I kill this process automatically when the debugger stops?

Comment: You could just close the program instead of `stop debugging`.

Comment: True, I could also make my process kill itself, I am hoping for for something related to stop debugging because I am so used to using that

Comment: What process are you starting? is it yours as well?

Comment: @Oskar yes, it is a process from a project contained in the same solution, but I start it as part of my application not during build or anything

Comment: @Cilvic why is a seperate process?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/0e81ca27-fb7c-4ed0-ad39-70b8e024747f

Comment: @Oskar, that's a bit of a longer story we have separate the process because we deal with real time processing of input events and if we don't separate than our GUI locks the OS event handling in certain scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Everybody who has a windows PC should have process explorer. It does a real "kill" on the process.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533

Some other good stuff there like listdlls.

Comment: I missed where he says that.  Perhaps you could be so kind as to point it out?

Comment: +1 for Wudang. Giving a link to a related software is not less than a helping hand. May be it is not the exact answer, but many viewers will be benificial by knowing that software.